# Laravel 5.7 y Ajax error 405 MethodNotAllowed

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, ajax

Tengo un pequeño formulario para registrar comentarios en una BBDD. Me gustaria poder hacerlo con Ajax pero no lo consigo ya que siempre me devuelve el error 405 "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message".

A ver si podéis ayudarme, gracias de antemano!

**blade file:**

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="addCommentForm">
                            @csrf
                            <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}" />
                            <input type="hidden" id="image_id" name="image_id" value="{{$image->id}}" />
                            <input type="hidden" id="token" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}" />
                            <input type="text" id="commentcontent" name="commentcontent" placeholder="{{__('messages.DoComment')}}" required />
                        </form>
```

El código de Javascript está dentro del mismo blade

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cleanfields(){
        $("#user_id").val('');
        $("#image_id").val('');
        $("#commentcontent").val('');
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $('#addCommentForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var user_id = $("input[name=user_id]").val();
        var image_id = $("input[name=image_id]").val();
        var CSRF_TOKEN = $ ('meta [nombre = "csrf-token"]'). attr ('contenido');
        var commentcontent = $("input[name=commentcontent]").val();
        
        
        $.ajax({
            type  :"POST",
            url     :"{{route('comment.add')}}",
            dataType:"json",
            data    :{ _token:CSRF_TOKEN, _method:'POST', user_id:user_id, image_id:image_id, commentcontent:commentcontent },
            success :function(response){
            alert("thank u");
            },
            error: function (error) {//add this also so you can get error if uccers
                 console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**web.php**:
La ruta es la siguiente

```
Route::post('/comment-add', 'CommentController@add')->name('comment.add');
```

**Controller**:
El metodo del Controller es el siguiente

```
public function add(Request $request) {
    $user_id = $request->input('user_id');
    $image_id = $request->input('image_id');
    $commentcontent = $request->input('commentcontent');
    
    $comment = new Comment();
    
    $comment->user_id = $user_id;
    $comment->image_id = $image_id;
    $comment->content = $commentcontent;
    
    $comment->save();
 
    return back();
}
```

**Head layout**:

```
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: En el ajax a tu ruta no la deberias llamar: url    ` :"{{route('/comment-add')}}"`, como la tienes declarada en el web.php?

Comment: Hola @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz, aunque lo he probado no hace falta, ya que el código del ajax no está en un .js separado y por tanto se puede poner la url por la propiedad "name". Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he logrado que funcione. Expongo aqui los cambios.

El código javascript del archivo blade lo he pasado arriba en vez de abajo quedando finalmente así:

```
function afegir(image_id){
        event.preventDefault();
        
        
        var user_id = $("#user_id"+image_id).val();
        var image_id = $("#image_id"+image_id).val();
        var method = $("input[name=_method]").val();
        var CSRF_TOKEN = $ ('meta [nombre = "csrf-token"]'). attr ('contenido');
        var commentcontent = $("#commentcontent"+image_id).val();
        
        if(commentcontent == (null || "")){
        }else{
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') },
                type  :"POST",
                url     :"{{route('comment.add')}}",
                dataType:"html",
                cache:false,
                data    :{ 
                    _token:CSRF_TOKEN,
                    _method:method,
                    user_id:user_id,
                    image_id:image_id, 
                    commentcontent:commentcontent
                },
                success :function(response){
                    $("#comments"+image_id).load(" #comments"+image_id);
                    cleanfields(image_id);
                },
                error: function (error) {//add this also so you can get error if uccers
                     console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

El método del Controller queda así:

```
public function add(Request $request) {
    
    $user_id = $request->input('user_id');
    $image_id = $request->input('image_id');
    $commentcontent = $request->input('commentcontent');
    
    
    
    $comment = new Comment();
    
    $comment->user_id = $user_id;
    $comment->image_id = $image_id;
    $comment->content = $commentcontent;
    
    $comment->save();
 
    return response('ok');
}
```

Y, finalmente, el formulario del archivo blade, así:

```
<form onsubmit="afegir({{$image->id}})" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="addCommentForm{{$image->id}}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="user_id{{$image->id}}" name="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}" />
                                    <input type="hidden" id="image_id{{$image->id}}" name="image_id" value="{{$image->id}}" />
                                    <input id="commentcontent{{$image->id}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="commentcontent{{$image->id}}" placeholder="{{__('messages.DoComment')}}" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Espero que pueda ser de ayuda en algún momento ;)

Saludos!